# Colour balancing SPOT5 ArcGIS Mosaic Dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mosaic, spot5

I'm working on a project using satellite imagery of a large braided river. I've been provide lots of SPOT5 images (that overlap). I've created a geodatabase, created a mosaic dataset, added the rasters to it, set the no data and set display order to max. A screen shot is shown below.

[image: Mosaic Dataset using SPOT5 data]

As you can see it has that patchy look to it. As I understand you resolve this by colour balancing.  I've spent much of this afternoon tinkering around with just about every combination of parameters. The overall mosaic dataset can change slightly or terribly depending upon my choice but I always still have that patchy look to it, just in a different intensity of colours.

Does colour balancing only work under some set of near perfect conditions (that is rarely obtained) and that generally most people end up with a patchy mosaic look as I have and that's about as good as it gets?

I have to admit this is my first dabbling into correcting satellite images so may be I have missed some step. I had a good look at the ESRI help and their walk-through and I can't see I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: One of your first steps should be image calibration and atmospheric correction to account for illumination angle, atmospheric dispersion and other issues related to moisture/clouds in the atmosphere, time of year, etc. Do you have access to any other software (e.g. ENVI)?

Comment: With no Answers offered in over a year, and some useful advice having already been provided as a Comment, would you be able to either write up an Answer, or edit your Question to revise it in line with your learnings, please?